# Why is this AR sum query returning double the expected result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am getting a strange result from an AR query. Using `sum` is giving a result that is double the expected result.

Some background

```
@parent.children.size
=> 1
@parent.children
=> [#<Child id: 1, date: "2016-01-01", quantity: 2>]
@parent.children.group_by_month_of_year(:date).count #using groupdate gem
=> {1=>1, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>0, 10=>0, 11=>0, 12=>0}
```

Why is this sum query returning `1 => 4`?

```
@parent.children.group_by_month_of_year(:date).sum(:quantity)
=> {1=>4, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>0, 7=>0, 8=>0, 9=>0, 10=>0, 11=>0, 12=>0}
```

With only 1 child record that has a `quantity` of 2, the query should return `1 => 2` shouldn't it?

How would I go about debugging this?

### EDIT

The query generates the following SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUM("purchases"."quantity") AS sum_quantity, 
EXTRACT(MONTH from date::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC' - INTERVAL '0 second')::integer 
AS extract_month_from_date_timestamptz_at_time_zone_etc_utc_interv 
FROM "purchases" 
INNER JOIN "people" ON "purchases"."person_id" = "people"."id" 
INNER JOIN "events" ON "people"."id" = "events"."person_id" 
WHERE "events"."location_id" = $1 AND (date IS NOT NULL) 
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH from date::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'Etc/UTC'  INTERVAL '0 second')::integer  
[["location_id", 1]]
```

with the following relationships

```
class Location
  has_many :events
  has_many :people, -> { distinct }, through: :events
  has_many :purchases, -> { distinct }, through: :people
end

class Event
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person
  has_many :events
  has_many :purchases
end

class Purchase
  belongs_to :person
end
```

## Edit 2

after altering how relationships are defined (as below), the sum query is calculating the correct result.

```
class Location  
  has_many :events
  has_many :people, -> { distinct }, through: :events
  def purchases
    Purchase.where( person_id: self.people.pluck(:id)
  end 
end
```

Comment: What SQL is it generating?

Comment: @DavidAldridge I've added the SQL and associations to the question. It is a somewhat complex relationship, so perhaps need to improve the query?

Comment: You will also have a problem if there are records across multiple years in the same month.  Eg.  A purchase happens on 2015-Jan-01 and another on 2016-Jan-17, these two purchases will get grouped into the same month rather than separate months.  You will likely need to group by month and year.

Answer (score 0):

Using distinct in the associations is not effective when you aggregate in this way. If there are multiple join paths between the location and the purchase, the distinct is applied to the final aggregated result, not to the underlying un-aggregated result set.

I'm not sure that the data model is even valid. If you are trying to get the sales per location via person and event, how do you know that the purchase was associated with a particular event and therefore a particular location?

Don't you need to link the purchase to both the person and the event, either directly by adding event_id to the purchase, or implicitly by having a time range on the events that you compare with the time of the purchase?

Edit:

In the context of understanding better what you're trying to do, how about this ...

```
Purchase.where(person: Person.joins(:events).where(events: {location_id: @location.id}).uniq).
         group_by_month_of_year(:date).sum(:quantity)
```

Comment: Thanks @david. The data model is valid. I want all purchases made by people who are associated with the event/location, not all purchases associated with the event/location. Grouping of multiple years is not a problem in this example. I'm still stuck as to why the query is calculating `4` when the expected response is `2`.

Comment: Thanks @david. based on your suggestions, I have altered how the relationships are defined (see edits above). The query now sums and returns the expected resulted. I would be very interested to better understand why this is happening. In particular, I am finding it very difficult to understand how the code in the 'background" section above all indicates that the only value available to sum is `2`, and yet the sum query is returning `4`. Would appreciate any thoughts you have, that can help me understand this better.

Comment: @AndyHarvey It's just that you have multiple potential join paths from a Location row to a Person, because they can be associated with the Location through multiple Events. This causes the aggregation to double (triple etc) the rows. The distinct is applied to the result after the aggregation has done this.